# A regular expression to exclude a special character

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, pattern-matching

In Spring MVC For validation use @Pattern annotation like this:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "???", message = "#i18n{obligatoire}")
@NotEmpty   
private String stringTest;
```

I want just exclude `&` character.  `@Pattern(regexp = "^&")` it's correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^[^&]*?$` is [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Oiv5uX/2) you are looking for.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[^&]*$")
@NotEmpty   
private String stringTest;
```

Explanation:

- `[^&]` captures any character that is not `&`
- `[^&]*` captures all characters that are not `&`
- `^[^&]*$` captures all characters on the line (`^` is the beggining of the line, `$` is the end of the line) that are not `&`